# Dispose RxJava 2 Chain on Singletons

Tags: android, singleton, rx-java2

I have some **RxJava 2 chains on a Singleton on an Android App**.
Now Android Studio now shows ***warnings*** for this type of code:

```
          myObservable
          .subscribe { doStuff() }
```

> The result of subscribe is not used

I assume it is done assuming that most chains will be used somewhere that is afected by a lifecycle and its a generic message.
But.. on a **Singleton that doesn't have any lifecycle** would it add some value to do this:

```
lateinit var disposable : Disposable 

 disposable = myObservable
              .doOnTerminate { disposable.dispose() }
              .subscribe { doStuff() }
```

Or is it just better to suppress the warning since RxJava 2 will dispose the chain after onComplete?

**I assume I should just suppress but I would like validation.**

Anyway would it make any different if it was a BehaviorSubject? I also assume it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, what you figured out by yourself already:

**Yes**, you can simply ignore this warning in singleton classes, exactly because singletons don't have an explicit life-cycle.

Singletons will be disposed together with the app itself and that means everything will be removed from memory.

Simply annotate the singleton class with:

```
@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
```

But this applies to **true singletons only**, so not to any other scoped components.